# Cross e-mail client HTML mail v:rect button width of 100 percent

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, mailchimp, email-templates

I've got this ugly code for creating a button in HTML email for MS Outlook:

```
  <!--[if mso]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank" style="height:50px;width:100%;v-text-anchor:middle;" stroke="f" fillcolor="#009CDE">
      <w:anchorlock/>
      <center>Watch the brand commercial</center>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
```

When I use a width of `600px` it does work. But when I resize the screen in MS outlook it isn't responsive.

But if I use a with of `100%` it breaks. So is it somehow possible to use a width of `100%` on `v:rect` element?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `width:100%` for v:rect, use `mso-width-percent:1000;`

1000 = 100%

But why make a headache for yourself? Create a responsive button that works in Outlook *and* everywhere else with, you guessed it, a table!

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="one-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
                <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <center>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#D90432" width="200" style="-moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 15px; border: none; line-height:20px;color:#ffffff;">
                                                <a href="https://www.google.com.au" style="text-decoration: none;color:#ffffff;display:block;">Watch This</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you can just use an anchor tag, but in Outlook you lose the background.

Comment: Sounds promising. I will try it out at work for the next mailings.

Comment: I tried using mso-width-percent but the width is based on the viewport width, rather than on the parent width :(